# Swiss pairings software ignoring colors?

Tags: software, swiss-pairing, shogi

I am looking for a tool that could manage a tournament and calculate the pairings (with Swiss or accelerated Swiss system) with an option to ignore black and white colors.

This software, with the option activated, would not take into account the prefered color of any player (no "you had White in round 1, so you should have Black in round 2") but otherwise apply all the usual rules for Swiss system (split players in a same bracket by rating, manage floating players, forbid facing twice the same opponent, etc).

Does such a software exists ?

The purpose is to use it for 1v1 sports without colors (e.g. tennis) or for games where colors are not attributed but picked at ramdom before the game (e.g., shogi). Internet searches have not brought satisfying results.

Answer (score 1):

Try [*Sevilla* by *JBF Software*](https://www.jbfsoftware.com/). Sevilla supports match and minor scores, e.g. 2-0, (3-2). Amalfi-pairing is also supported.

Some configuration is required as the program focuses on chess.